# PHP Hamcrest matchers to assert partial array key/val pair content

Tags: php, unit-testing, hamcrest

I am testing my code with PHP and using Hamcrest matchers and I am wanting to assert that my returned array contains a particular key/value pair, however I am struggling.

For example, my array returns `['wanted-value' => 'some-value', 'arbitrary-value' => 'who-cares']`

I want to assert that the returned array contains `'wanted-value' => 'some-value'` but I don't care what else is in there.

I have seen `arrayContaining` used, but from what I can tell this only looks for a value or key, but not both?

Answer (score 0):

Who would have thought the official docs would have the answer?
To be honest, I didn't know PHP docs for Hamcrest actually existed, I'd always just seen it as JAVA-specific.

The solution: `hasKeyValuePair`

```
assertThat($result, hasKeyValuePair('wanted-value', 'some-value'));
```